# Drupal Webform - CiviCRM - PayPal Website Payment Standard - Email Required Issue

Tags: webform-civicrm

I am using Drupal 7.53, Webforms 7.x, CiviCRM 4.7.13 with PayPal Website Payment Standard. On checkout in the Webform it is requiring email and we have email in the webform. We can't manipulate billing. Any ideas on how to force this to work?

Comment: I figured it out. I had two email fields and the first email listed is the assumed billing address.

Comment: Could you post this as an answer, then check it as accepted? That will provide more benefit to other users as it will be parsed correctly.

Comment: Joe - thanks for the direction. I was trying to figure out how to close the question and moved on before I could figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. I had two email fields and the first email listed is the assumed billing address